# Select query showing incorrect order in DB2

Tags: db2, sql-insert

While inserting the data in the database third record that is coming is first record at the time of insertion and the first record is second and third one is fourth and so on.

I am using the following query to fetch the data:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F FROM MYTABLE WHERE A = 'SOMEPGM' ORDER BY F
```

F have duplicate records...

why first record becomes third record in the result?

Answer (score 4):

You are doing `ORDER BY "MGRSEQ"`, but there are rows with duplicate `MGRSEQ` values; you need to specify another column to get a consistent ordering. Ordering without explicit `ORDER BY` clauses is not guaranteed.

Comment: +1 - Agreed.  **NEVER** rely on implicit ordering in SQL, as the optimizer is free to do whatever it wants (pretty much).

Comment: Yup. The worst part is that most DBMSs return rows in insertion order *most of the time*, which in turn leads to software that relies on this and will fail randomly.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT "MGRROUT", "MGRTYP", "MGRRRN", "MGRNUM", "MGROPC", 
       "MGRVAR1", "MGRCOMP", "MGRVAR2", "MGREXC", "MGRSEQ", MGRCAT1 
FROM "XPGMLOGIC" WHERE "MGRPGM" = 'BARSCSLMS' 
ORDER BY "MGRSEQ", "MGRNUM" DESC
```